# Cannot draw texture image

Tags: texture-painting

I am trying to draw color to a duplicated face. If someone could help me, it would be very appreciated. I am actually working on eye painting but tried if easy sample also have same problem or not then it happened.

What I did was below.

1. Create a new general which have a cube.
2. Select face (3) below in picture right pane and duplicate it(shift + D) and move to (2).
3. Put a loop cut which is (4).
4. Select (4) and duplicate it(shift + D).
5. Move the duplicated edge and move to (1) place.
6. Grid fill the edge.
7. Select all and made a texture paint slot.
8. Paint on unwrapped 2D in left pane.

[image]

I can see the blue paint was applied to cube and duplicated face which is (2). However, never be able to paint on (1). I even tried to paint on right pane but also that did not work.
I went to Edit mode on right pane then select each face. Other than (1), I can see the face was selected on left pane but nothing I could see for (1) selected.

I guess, it does not recognized as a face in blender. Can anyone help me to do fix this situation? I would like to paint on (1). Thank you for your support, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The new plane (1) has no UV coordinates. You have to select all faces and unwrap them. Then you should be able to paint on all.

Comment: omg,,, the unwrapped development was created automatically, So, I thought that it will applied the change automatically. I confirmed it is working and also on my eye object... I had unwrapped on the eye before I think...  But anyway, now I can paint what I wanted. Thank you so much for your kind support!!

Comment: You're welcome.
Please mark my answer as the right one or useful for other users. You can do this with the arrows on the left, beside my post. Thank you.